# How to return the row index of each element from a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 8x10 2D array, A. I need another 2D array that stores only the **row** index of each element of A. How do I go about doing so? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!

`C = np.array(np.where(A))[0].reshape(10, 8)`